# Add custom tab to Magento product detail pages depending on category

Tags: php, magento, magento-layout-xml

In our Magento store we offer two kinds of products, each with their own root categories. I want to add CMS Static Blocks as custom tabs on product detail pages that are dependent on which category the product is under.

I know how to create tabs in the `view.phtml` template, but how can I make it so that:

- **Block 1** appears on product detail pages under root **Category 1**
- **Block 2** appears on product detail pages under root **Category 2**

I think it is possible with XML layout updates to remove and append tabs, but how do I append the blocks to the layout?

Comment: If you can add Tabs in view.phtml directly then you can add catgeory condition on view.phtml for each tab depending on category

Comment: can you explain it a bit more in detail? im not a developer. sorry

Answer (score 1):

### Overview

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to add a custom tab on the product detail page when viewing the product under your two special categories (category1 and category2).

The tabs on the product detail page are of type `catalog/product_view_tabs` which normally maps to the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Tabs`. This block does provide a way to add new tabs through its `addTab()` method, but it seems that this method assumes a template will be used, which unfortunately prevents using a CMS Static Block with this method.

### A Possible Solution

If you are able to put your content from the two static blocks into two template files instead, you could do this using layout XML updates on the categories themselves. I will outline the process you would use in this scenario:

1. Navigate to ***Catalog > Categories > Manage Categories*** in Magento Admin and click on category1 in the tree.
2. Open the ***Custom Design*** tab.
3. Set “Apply To Products” to *Yes*.
4. Now add the layout update for that category’s products that should have the custom tab under “Custom Layout Update”:

---

```
<reference name="content">
    <reference name="product.info.tabs">
        <action method="addTab" translate="title">
            <alias>block1</alias>
            <title>Block 1</title>
            <block>core/template</block>
            <template>catalog/product/view/block1.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</reference>
```

It should look something like this:
[image]

Then just repeat the same steps for category2. The key to this solution working is to get your two template files `block1.phtml` and `block2.phtml` into the path: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/`.

Comment: hello @fantasticrice ! Thanks for your help! Is it possible that the reference name changed by using a custom template? i try to add this xml update to the categories but magento dont add a tab. maybe i had to modify your xml code?

Comment: @Micha - My solution assumes standard templates, wouldn't know how to help with your custom code.